Google Colab: keep multiple outputs of one cell *pretty*
During my Data Science workflow, it's not uncommon that I pass multiple columns through the same data-overview functions like .info .describe .hist .box and so on. One function - one cell. And scrolling from one cell to the other becomes tedious very quickly, since you have to change the target column each time, and click 'execute', and click, and click.
I wonder if there is a way to put all the data-overview functions into one cell, while keeping the prettiness of the output? Right now you either keep all the functions separate, which is not convenient. Or you do put functions into one cell, and use print or fancy subplots, and the output becomes meh.
I've found SymPy: How can i output multiple LaTex equations in one cell in Google Colab? and it links to the https://www.roelpeters.be/jupyter-notebooks-how-to-print-multiple-outputs-in-a-cell/. It makes the cell give out everything it has. While useful for the data-overview workflow, the entire Colab notebook suffers greatly. The rest of it, the data-processing part, now has to include negations of the cell behavior everywhere.
One workaround I thought of while typing is: you put the data-overview functions under one heading, leave a column identification variable above it, collapse the heading and click "run" that is associated with it. The problem is, I now can't look at the results of the overview for multiple columns simultaneously.
What is the consensus on working with Data Science in Google Colab anyway? I feel like I'm missing something

"What is the consensus on working with Data Science in Google Colab anyway?" Keep in mind it is a large corporation adapting a freely available open source software as an entryway into getting you to pay for computer. You can use more modern Jupyter on your machine with Jupyter Desktop. Or if you need more complex environment and project management look into installing the Anaconda Disttribution. Or use Anaconda Cloud.

As to your question about functions and cells...You mention print() but you seem to be using a lot of Pandas stuff. You should be using display() in Jupyter if you are working with Pandas and many other modern packages. And in 'the bigger picture', there's a lot of ways to control output in Jupyter. Your pose is getting downvoted because it doesn't stick with the typical one question, one post expect on StackOverflow. If you had a specific example case it would go a long way to making this better. You also may find it is more suitable of a discussion at the Jupyter Discourse forum ...

 if you are willing to generalize beyond the specialized Google Colab and ask more about Jupyter. (At this time, Google Colab is a fork of very old Jupyter tech that doesn't keep up with the newer abilities & features Jupyter has these days.)
